# Error when using pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

So, i'm trying to convert a unix column of dates to a more legible time expression. In order to achieve that i use the command

```
`df1["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"],origin='unix')`
```

how ever it returns the dates with the following structure.

```
1970-01-01 00:00:01.521673397  xxx              
1970-01-01 00:00:01.521673200  yyy      
1970-01-01 00:00:01.521672938  zzz
```

i would really apreciate if i can get a little help.
ps:the first, second and third dates in unix are `1521673397;1521673200;1521672938`

Comment: What format do you want them in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unit` argument
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
ud = '1521673397;1521673200;1521672938'.split(';')
pd.to_datetime(ud, unit='s')

DatetimeIndex(['2018-03-21 23:03:17', '2018-03-21 23:00:00',
               '2018-03-21 22:55:38'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: @JoseTomasMarquez if this is what you need , can you consider accept it ? check mark at the left :-)

Comment: Oh, i was trying to do it before, i thought that it was the "thumbs up", lol.